# Shrink groupby rows by creating multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team A':['LU','LU','IU','IU','MS','MS'],'Team B':['IU','MU','LU','MS','IU','LU'],'score':[150,160,180,130,155,103]})
```

What I want to do, is to shrink the rows, such that each row has unique value by creating multiple columns.
What I want to do is to create data frame like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'Team A':['LU','IU','MS'],'Team B':[150,180,155],'Team C':[160,130,103]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[['Team A', 'score']].set_index(['Team A', df.groupby('Team A').cumcount()])['score']\
                       .unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Team A    0    1
0     IU  180  130
1     LU  150  160
2     MS  155  103
```

Comment: I don't understand OP's column naming  scheme... but this is cute `pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in df.groupby('Team A').score])`

Comment: I hope you're staying safe.

Comment: OH, without sorting.  `pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in df.groupby('Team A', sort=False).score])`

Comment: @Scott Boston thanks alot, it worked. but i am still struggling to grab it, how it worked,

Comment: @TalhaAnwar, ScottBoston is creating an index for each score, zero for the first one, one for the next and so on.  By setting the index to be part `'Team A'` and part "new column that is counting scores", he gets a `MultiIndex` that he can then `unstack` into the form you are looking for. What I did was to leverage the knowledge that pandas can take a list of lists/tuples and that those lists/tuples don't have to be the same length.  I'm depending on Pandas to interpret the potential uneveness for me.  ScottBoston is being more explicit.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, indeed that is a neat solution.  Unpacking series nice!

Comment: @piRSquared I am pretty safe here in Houston... Except for that -27 dollar per bbl of oil.

Comment: I wish I had a place to store it... or even transport it.  I'd be there right now.

Comment: @TalhaAnwar the equivalent of what I did would be `pd.DataFrame([(a, b, *s) for (a, b), s in df.groupby(['Team A', 'Team B']).score])`  However, this has a potential to break.  You need understanding of what you want.  I'm making assumptions about discarding information in the name of the players and what you are putting into the column names.